# Run rcp.statd without systemd (Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL))

Tags: systemd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run certain mount commands, I am told

```
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
```

The command I find online to start statd is:

```
systemctl start statd
```

which gives anothe error:

```
> systemctl start statd
Failed to add /run/systemd/ask-password to directory watch: No such file or directory
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

[Other sources](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1579#issuecomment-271555310) make it clear that there is no systemd on Ubuntu WSL.

How can I start statd without systemd?

Answer (score 1):

`systemd` ultimately just run binaries. So without `systemd`, you can the binaries directly.

If you need the binary to run the background. you can run it `nohup`.

If you need the process to be *managed* then you'll need another tool that can do things like start it on boot and automatically restart it if fails.